# android: help in exception error (line number)

Tags: android, exception, error-handling

I just want to know one thing.. I have a client who has complaint that the application crashes when loading. I asked him to provide me with the error code.. He gave me with the error code, with the help of the error code, I know which function is causing error but I need to go to the exact line of code.. the code appears like :

```
at com.myapplication.MainActivity.deviceInfo(MainActivity.java:**870**)
at com.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:**97**)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:**1047**)
```

my question is, what does 870, 97 and 1047 means in the above error code; I think it is line number. if it is line number then SOMEONE PLEASE TELL ME HOW TO GET TO THIS LINE NUMBER..

Thanks alot

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. I'd say you go to folder with MainActivity.java, open it in some editor, turn on line numbering and find line with number 870. May be I don't understand something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either I don't understand the question or you are very new with Java debugging, but yes, 870, 97 and 1047 are the line number in your code.

It's part of the stacktrace where the exception has occurred. The line numbers have to match the version of the source file at the time you gave you give your application to your client (hopefully, you have still that version via archiving somewhere or branching in your source control).

Once you have that version of the file, you simply go there and check the line numbers and start from there.

If this is not your question, please clarify it further